# Unable to use Ace as RequireJS dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ace-editor

I'm trying to use Ace with RequireJS, but this code below is not working. The Ace script was downloaded, but the required parameter `ace` is always `undefined`.

```
requirejs(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.3/ace.js'], function (ace /*always undefined*/) {
  console.log(ace);
});
```

I'm using RequireJS 2.3.6

[image: Screenshot from 2019-03-24 16-26-55]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, in order to work, you need to configure a path in *requirejs* configuration pointing to the CDN folder:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        ace: ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.3/']
    }
});
```

and then require the ace module:

```
requirejs(['ace/ace'], function (ace) {
    console.log(ace);
});
```

Comment: This works, but why should we use `'ace/ace'` in the required list?

Comment: In the path we are only setting the CDN folder, so we need to specify the module name in the requirejs statement.